# How to Remove Code Analysis Warning CA1006?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative to nested type of type Expression<Func<T>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441563/alternative-to-nested-type-of-type-expressionfunct)

Playing with a method in a Facade / Repository, gleaned from a MSDN article, I produced:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Fetch(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy,
    string includeProperties)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.DbContext.Set<TEntity>();

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(includeProperties))
    {
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties
            .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
    }

    return orderBy == null 
        ? query 
        : orderBy(query);
}
```

Code Analysis generates 2 warnings, as follows:

> CA1006 : Microsoft.Design : Consider a design where
>   '`MyType<TDbContext, TEntity>.Fetch(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>,
>   Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>, string)`'
>   doesn't nest generic type '`Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`'.
>
> CA1006 : Microsoft.Design : Consider a design where
>   '`MyType<TDbContext, TEntity>.Fetch(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>,
>   Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>, string)`'
>   doesn't nest generic type '`Func<IQueryable<TEntity>,
>   IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>>`'.

Now, I know they are only warnings and I am free to suppress them (and probably will as they appear overly pedantic under this scenario). However, out of interest, is there a possible design that accomplishes the same as this method without incurring the Code Analysis warnings?

Richard